Imprimir número de página según cantidad de hojas en Word - Excel
Necesito imprimir 100 copias de un archivo, pero que cambie el número de página por cada página impresa, sin la necesidad generar 100 copias de la hoja que quiero imprimir

Parece que no es fácil.  Aquí está una página en inglés http://www.gmayor.com/automatic_numbering_documents.htm con una respuesta

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Me encanta cuando te molestas en responder y no vuelven a entrar para consultar su pregunta...

Con una macro puedes hacerlo. En Excel inserta este código en un módulo vba:
Sub ImprimirConNumerosDePagina()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
    
    For i = 1 To 100
        ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Página " & i
        ws.PrintOut
    Next i
End Sub

Sólo tienes que cambiar el nombre de la hoja (Hoja1) por el de tu documento.
Para Word sería algo parecido:
Sub ImprimirConNumerosDePagina()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    For i = 1 To 100
        doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Página " & i
        doc.PrintOut
    Next i
End Sub

Puede que tan solo te haga falta especificar donde quieres colocar el número de página. Eso ya a tu gusto.
